# Opening protected page with cookie?

Tags: login, cookies, authentication

I'm working on an app that uses WordPress for user management. After login, the app holds the auth cookie. How can I use that cookie to open a web view of a protected page within the app without requiring the user to login again?

Can the app specify some header parameter? Or a URL query parametr? A plugin that provides this type of functionality?

**Update:** The auth cookie is initially fetched using the [JSON API User plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/).

Answer (score 0):

Was simpler than I thought, but surprisingly little information about this. A client can request a protected page by specifying the cookie with a `cookie` query parameter:

```
http://{wordpress-installation}/user?cookie={cookie}
```